# plotly express | change tick units on y axis

Tags: python, express, formatting, plotly, axis

I want to add units to my yaxis of my bar chart.
Im using plotly.express for that but didnt found a working solution inside the documentation.
text_auto() and fig.update_layout() are not working for me right now.
(Tried that thread without success -> [Changing Text Inside Plotly Express Bar Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73312960/changing-text-inside-plotly-express-bar-charts))

Im not using panda data format right now, rather a own dictionary i feed plotly.

Please bear with me as im still new to analysing data with plotly.

[image: How it looks now without units for eacht tick.]

```
import json
import requests
from operator import itemgetter
import plotly.express as px

#hyperlinks = xaxis with description and link to the game
#times = yaxis total playtime (<- where i want to use "xx.xh")
#titles = simple hover text
df = {
    "x" : hyperlinks,
    "y" : times,
    "titles" : titles,
    }   

fig = px.bar(
    df,
    x="x", 
    y="y",
    hover_data=["titles"],
    color="y",
    color_continuous_scale="Plotly3_r",
    title=f"Top 30 games with most playtime",
    text_auto=".h",
    labels={"y" : "entire playtime of steam games"},
    )

fig.update_layout(
    yaxis={
        "tickformat" : '.h'
        }
    )
fig.show()
fig.write_html("My_most_played_games.html")
```

Comment: what unit would you like to add?

Comment: `labels={"y" : "entire playtime of steam games (hrs)"}`

Comment: @Lucas M. Uriarte Id like to add "h" to the y axis.

Comment: @404rorre to every tick value or in general. If the second the comment from Mehmaan is your solution

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte to every tick value. If thats possible. :)

Comment: @404rorre I have posted an answer let me know if that worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have generated some random values for the example.

Since recently you can have access to figure parameters of plotly using `fig.full_figure_for_development()` from there you can extract element to check where plotly added ticks and regenerate them adding to them any string you want

```py
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
#hyperlinks = xaxis with description and link to the game
#times = yaxis total playtime (<- where i want to use "xx.xh")
#titles = simple hover text
df = {
    "x" : ['black desert', 'arma 3', 'borderland 2', 'Cyberpunk'],
    "y" : [420, 350, 310, 180],
    "titles" : ['black desert', 'arma 3', 'borderland 2', 'Cyberpunk'],
    }   

fig = px.bar(
    df,
    x="x", 
    y="y",
    hover_data=["titles"],
    color="y",
    color_continuous_scale="Plotly3_r",
    title=f"Top 30 games with most playtime",
    text_auto=".h",
    labels={"y" : "entire playtime of steam games"},
    )

# Important part to recover infor from the figure
full_fig = fig.full_figure_for_development()  # recover data from figure
range_vl = full_fig.layout.yaxis.range  # get range of y axis
distance_tick = full_fig.layout.yaxis.dtick  # get distance between ticks

number_ticks = range_vl[1]//full_fig.layout.yaxis.dtick + 1 # calculate number of ticks of your figure

tick_vals = [range_vl[0]+distance_tick*num for num in range(int(number_ticks))] # generate your ticks
tick_text = [f"{val} h" for val in tick_vals] #generate text for your ticks

fig.update_layout(
    # set tick mode to array, tickvals to your vals calculated and tick text  to the text genrated
    yaxis={"tickmode":"array","tickvals":tick_vals, "ticktext": tick_text}
        
    )
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution! It has a little flaw on my API generated data though... My yaxis.dtick is 100 and my yaxis.range is 495.59 . My ticks reduce by half (every 100 one tick instead of every 50). Do you have an idea how to solve that? A brute option would be to half the dtick and double the number of ticks.
Love your eye opener though. It showed me a new way to explore plotly. :D

Comment: @404rorre I dont think there is anything wrong in your appi data. I just thing that your data are a bit different than the one I randomly generated and thus plotly automatically adjust the values as it think is the best. Your result is probably because the  real value for black dessert is bigger than 420. But if you want ticks every 50 just use that value, simply set ```distance_tick=50```. that would be enough.

Comment: @404rorre another nice feature about plorly is that everything are dictionaries. If you want to check want is behind scenes of your figure just use ```print(fig)``` you will be surprise. :)

Comment: Ive been doing it for the last 2h to get a more profound grasp of your solution and beyond. ;)
But i was stuck at where you get the key arguments for fig.update_layout().
->yaxis={"tickmode":"array","tickvals":tick_vals, "ticktext": tick_text})
(found them in deeper documentations right now ;))
THOUGH!
What is your way to go to search for specific values you wanna change?
(Took me 2h to understand/explore. I wanna reduce that time. Albeit i enjoyed it. ^^)